# An intelligent Javascript back button that doesnt use history()

Tags: javascript

Im developing on a platform that has some limitations on how i can implement a proper back button.

So i need to create a button that does more then just *"javascript:history.back()"*

Let me explain:

**page1**...clicks through to...
**page2**...fill in the fields and submit to itself...
**page2?something=else**... here is where the back button is needed

on **page2?something=else** i want the back button to take the user back to **page1**

**page1** = could be any page (so cant link directly)

is there a function that will know changes in the URL as well as remember the  URL when the page is submitted?

Please lety me know if you would like more info.

Thanks

Comment: what prevents them from hitting the back button in their browser?

Comment: @zzzzBov totally agree, just wish my project manager would think the same

Comment: understood. I assume you're sending form data for the `page2?something=else` part. If you're posting data to a script, you ought to send a unique_id to be checked against to prevent accidental double-submission.

Comment: This might be overkill, but, if the browser is in a controlled environment, then you might even want to consider creating an extension (eg, for firefox).

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is during the form submission on **page2**.  Where it would normally submit a form to itself, your script would intercept the submit action and replace the current item in the history instead.  In order to do this, you would need to reconstruct the query string values:

```
myForm.onsubmit = function () {
    var url = this.action,   // The URL where the form is submitted
        els = this.elements, // A list of all the input elements
        qs  = "?",           // The query string we're constructing
        enc = function (s) { // Function for encoding
            return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/%20/g, "+");
        };

    for (var i=0, max = els.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (els[i].disabled || !els[i].name)
            continue;

        qs += enc(els[i].name) + "=" + enc(els[i].value) + "&"; 
    }

    // chop off the final ampersand
    qs = qs.slice(0, -1);

    // Replace the current entry in the history
    window.location.replace(action + qs);

    // Cancel the default form submission
    return false;
}
```

It will probably need a little refinement to suit your needs but you get the general idea.  Now both the browser's back button and your own back button should return to **page1**.  This approach won't work for POST submissions, however.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways you could solve this problem.

The first of these depends on the assumption that the number of history pages between `Page1` and `page2?something=else` is always the same.

```
javascript: window.history.go(-2)
```

Notice the -2 this tells the browser how many pages to go back.

The second option which would be more laborious, but ultimately a lot more reliable, would be to store the current users breadcrumb (i.e. the pages they have transitted through) in a session and then use the session data to construct your back link.

A third option would be to pass the page/address the back link should point to as post/get parameters through all pages.  When the user hits the page that the back link appears on you can then use that data to construct the back link.

A fourth option would be to combine the first with either the second or third solution.  i.e. pass the history count through on sessions/get/post and then use that to populate the number that goes into the Javascript `.go(x)` function

Comment: you make it sound so simple. however those options are not appropriate in my case, however, i think youve put me on the right lines with combining 1 with 3... will post my solution here